# Implementing Objective C delegate in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, swift-protocols

I have a Objective C class that has methods that look like this:

```
@class Client;

@protocol ClientDelegate <NSObject>

@optional
-(void) receivedMessageFromClient : (id) message;

@end

@interface Client : NSObject 

+(id) setup; 
 @property(nonatomic, strong) id <ClientDelegate> clientDelegate;

// more method declarations below
```

I am implementing the ClientDelegate in my Swift class like this:

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController, ClientDelegate {
    var client : AnyObject?
    var delegate: ClientDelegate?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        client = Client.setup() as! Client
         client.clientDelegate = self
    }

func receivedMessageFromClient(message: AnyObject) {
        print("Message recieved: \(message)")
    }
}
```

This is giving me a compiling error:

> Cannot assign to property: 'self' is immutable

When I remove the lines

```
client = Client.setup() as! Client
client.clientDelegate = self
```

the code compiles and calls the method in the Client class that in turns sends a message to `receivedMessageFromClient`, but the method is not called in `HomeViewController`. It seems that everything is setup with the exception of assigning self to be the delegate.

Comment: Delegates usually have `weak` attribute instead of `strong`. And RTFM about protocols https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I am using objective-c classes in swift2 , how i can implement delegate methods and bind that delegate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33774912/i-am-using-objective-c-classes-in-swift2-how-i-can-implement-delegate-methods)

Comment: do you have a bridging header ?

Comment: yes, and it is working. I am able to call and use methods of the class

Comment: Reading your code, I think you need to revise the delegation pattern [check this out](http://www.alexefish.com/post/522641eb31fa2a0015000002). You first need to sort out your delegate in objective c then implement it in Swift.

Answer (score 11):

Check out my comments on your question but this is a basic example of an Objective-C delegate implemented in Swift:

> Objective-C:

```
@protocol MyDelegate <NSObject>

@optional
- (void)canImplementThis:(int)aVar;
@required
- (BOOL)needToImplementThis;

@end

@interface MyClass : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<MyDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

> Swift:

```
class SwiftClass : UIViewController, MyDelegate {

    var myObj : MyClass?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        myObj = MyClass()
        myObj?.delegate = self
    }

    // MARK: - <MyDelegate>

    func canImplementThis(aVar : Int) {
        print("Called: \(aVar))
    }

    func needToImplementThis() -> Bool {
        return false
    }

}
```

Forgive any typos I typed this out straight into SO.

Comment: how to call `needToImplementThis` or `canImplementThis` in objective-c?

Comment: found out: `[_delegate method:value];`, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Had to change Int to Int32 for some reason so it fix the invalid selector issue, with Int32 on the swift side but then worked